# Display dynamic content from embedded web server

Tags: embedded-systems, http, dynamic-data

I have an embedded device running a slimmed down version of a HTTP server. Currently, it can display static HTML pages. Here is an example of how it displays a static HTML page:

```
char *text="HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n"
"<html><body>Hello World!</body></html>";
IPWrite(socket, (uint8*)text, (int)strlen(text));
IPClose(socket);
```

What I'd like to do is display dynamic content, e.g. a reading from a sensor. What I thought of so far is to have the page refresh every once in awhile with

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600">
```

and use sprintf() to attach the sensor reading to the *text* variable for the response.

Is there a way I can do this without having to refresh the page constantly?

Comment: What web server are you running a "slimmed down version" of?

Comment: It's a custom HTTP server written for the [Plasma RTOS](http://opencores.org/project,plasma)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could theoretically implement [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets) on your server. And have the server fire updates manually. Either that or use [long polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_polling#Long_polling). The tough part for you would be implementing either properly. But it could be done.